# Segue main ViewController from side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uistoryboardsegue

I am in development of an app that can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rileylloyd24/Cazenovia-Slide-Menu) and I can't figure out how to segue with the sliding side menu. The idea is that the main ViewController will change to a different view that is selected in the side menu (without back arrows) and then have the main ViewController slide back in. I can get the ViewController to slide, but I can't get the segue right. I am currently trying to segue to 'CalendarView.XIB' from 'ViewController.m' when the 'Calendar' button is pressed from the side menu.

ViewController.m:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Pressed 0");
        BlogView *blogView = [[BlogView alloc] init];
        [self.puView addSubview:blogView];
        [self hideMenu];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Pressed 1");
        TwitterView *twitView = [[TwitterView alloc] init];
        [self hideMenu];
        [self.puView addSubview:twitView];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Pressed 2");
        PowerView *pschoolView = [[PowerView alloc] init];
        [self hideMenu];
        [self.puView addSubview:pschoolView];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        NSLog(@"Pressed 3");
        CalendarView *calView = [[CalendarView alloc] init];
        [self.puView addSubview:calView];
        [self hideMenu];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error");
        //ErrorView *errorV = [[ErrorView alloc] init];
        //[self hideMenu];
        //[self.puView addSubview:errorV];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't loaded the nib, here is an example for just the calendar:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CalendarView" owner:self options:nil];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        ....
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        NSLog(@"Pressed 3");
        CalendarView *calView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.puView addSubview:calView];
        [self hideMenu];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}
```

So do the same for each menu Item.

Answer (score 0):

if your using a story board control manually create the segues and set the identifiers the call them using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER" sender:nil];
```

best i can think of :)